# How to Count Text Lines in R?

Tags: r, text, count

I would like to calculate the number of lines spoken by different speakers from a text using R (it is a transcript of parliamentary speaking records). The basic text looks like:

```
MR. JOHN: This activity has been going on in Tororo and I took it up with the office of the DPC. He told me that he was not aware of it.
MS. SMITH: Yes, I am aware of that. 
MR. LEHMAN: Therefore, I am seeking your guidance, Madam Speaker, and requesting that you re-assign the duty.  
MR. JOHN: Thank you
```

In the documents, each speaker has an identifier that begins with MR/MS and is always capitalized. I would like to create a dataset that counts the number of lines spoken for each speaker for each time spoke in a document such that the above text would result in:

```
MR. JOHN: 2
MS. SMITH: 1
MR. LEHMAN: 2
MR. JOHN: 1
```

Thanks for pointers using R!

Comment: Check out the read.transcript function in the qdap package.

Comment: What format is the data in?  .docx?

Comment: I am unclear why Mr. John has a '2' the first time.  Does the '2' refer to the number of sentences he spoke?  He spoke two sentences in one line and one sentence in another line.  I am also unclear why Mr. Lehman has a '2'.  He only spoke one sentence and one line in your example.  Does each row always begin with MR. or MS.?  For example, if Mr. X was verbose and spoke three paragraphs uniterupted would all of that speech be on one line?  If not, would each line of the speech begin with MR. X:?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the pattern `:` to split the string by and then use `table`:

```
table(sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), "[[", 1))
#   MR. JOHN MR. LEHMAN  MS. SMITH 
#          2          1          1
```

> strsplit - splits strings at `:` and results in a list
>   sapply with [[ - selects the first part element of the list
>   table - gets the frequency

**Edit:** Following OP's comment. You can save the transcripts in a *text file* and use `readLines` to read the text in R.

```
tt <- readLines("./tmp.txt")
```

Now, we'll have to find a pattern by which to filter this text for just those lines with the names of those who're speaking. I can think of two approaches based on what I saw in the transcript you linked.

- Check for a `:` and then *lookbehind* the `:` to see if it is any of `A-Z` or `[:punct:]` (that is, if the character occurring before the `:` is any of the capital letters or any punctuation marks - this is because some of them have a `)` before the `:`).

You can use `strsplit` followed by `sapply` (as shown below)

**Using strsplit:**

```
# filter tt by pattern
tt.f <- tt[grepl("(?<=[A-Z[:punct:]]):", tt, perl = TRUE)]
# Now you should only have the required lines, use the command above:

out <- table(sapply(strsplit(tt.f, ":"), "[[", 1))
```

There are other approaches possible (using `gsub` for ex:) or alternate patterns. But this should give you an idea of the approach. If the pattern should differ, then you should just change it to capture all required lines.

Of course, this assumes that there is no other line, for example, like this:

```
"Mr. Chariman, whatever (bla bla): It is not a problem"
```

Because our pattern will give TRUE for `):`. If this happens in the text, you'll have to find a better pattern.

Comment: +`t`. It doesn't make sense to post while you are awake. When do you sleep?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, It is 9PM here, while it is 1:20AM there! :)

Comment: Just a small addition in case @user2154571 doesn't know, you can read your lines of text to R using `x<-readLines("D:/text.txt")`

Comment: Hi all - Apologies for the lack of clarity there. I'm scraping from a website, the Ugandan parliament to code the transcripts; here is a link to an example transcript - http://www.parliament.go.ug/hansard/hans_view_date.jsp?dateYYYY=2009&dateMM=09&dateDD=21. I am downloading them as .txt files however can change that. The previous posting did not cut the lines where I anticipated, however MR. JOHN and MR. SMITH's first comments were both supposed to be two lengths in line (as would be apparent in a word document). The speaker's name is only included once when they begin speaking. Thanks!